# how to php only allow only special parameter in url or redirect to other

Tags: php

I need help to write function which help me clean out any unusual ( not allow in array list) then redirect to right url

eg my original is /modules.php?aaa=111&bbb=2

the var aaa and bbb is alow using on urls ,

if some one ads other var to url incase you mess up or want to overhead the server they will redirect back to original one.. but cut all invalid param out.

eg: /modules.php?aaa=111&notgood=999&bbb=2

will redirect back to

modules.php?aaa=111&bbb=2

the &notgood=999 or any other will be strip out..

```
$goodvar = array("aaa","bbb");
$requesturi = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if   /// Need help : if other query not in the list of good var will be clean out of requesturi to build NEWrequesturi
{
    header("Location: ".$NEWrequesturi,TRUE,301); exit; die(); 
}
```

thanks very much
kind regards

Comment: check all the items in the `$_GET` array, and if any of them are not parameters that you want to accept, then you can do your redirect. Although, it might be less user-unfriendly to simply ignore them. They can't do any harm if you just don't use them. I'm not sure this is actually necessarily worth your time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$good_var = ["aaa", "bbb"];
$query_params = explode(".php?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1];
$all_query_data = explode("&", $query_params);
$data_set = [];
foreach ($all_query_data as $query_value) {
    $param = explode("=", $query_value);
    $data_set[$param[0]] = $param[1];
}
$paased_args = array_keys($data_set);
if (empty(array_diff($paased_args, $good_var))) {
    echo "Url is good";
    // do whatever you want when url is good
} else {
    echo "Url tempered";
    //url has been tempered do as you wish
}
```